# How to migrate from MySQL.EntityFrameworkCore to Pomelo.EntityframeworkCore

Tags: entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I've got a production system that I'd like to migrate from using MySQL.EntityframeworkCore to Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore. I wanted to do some due diligence before I just upgraded the nuget packages and give it a spin. I appreciate any insight. Currently I'm on EF5, also planning on upping to EF6.

One area of concern is existing migrations. Will they be compatible? Early in the project I switched from MSSQL provider to MySQL and had to delete and regenerate the migrations from scratch.

Comment: You could, you know, try it out... Migrations aren't guaranteed to be compatible though, but it might work.

Comment: Just try, it should be easy. If not, just remember that official provider do not support asyncs.

Comment: right right... I'll just try it :)